# python setup.py sdist and custom setup keywords don't play together

Tags: python, setuptools

### subtitle: Not only sdist

I am trying to get the `setup.py` file of a package I'm working on to play nicely with `sdist`. The relevant parts of the `setup.py` file are:

```
from setuptools.command.test import test
[...]
class Tox(test):
   "as described in 
    http://tox.readthedocs.org/en/latest/example/basic.html?highlight=setuptools#integration-with-setuptools-distribute-test-commands"
   [...]
def run_tests(self):
    if self.distribution.install_requires:
        self.distribution.fetch_build_eggs(
            self.distribution.install_requires)
    if self.distribution.tox_requires:
        self.distribution.fetch_build_eggs(self.distribution.tox_requires)
    # import here, cause outside the eggs aren't loaded
    import tox
    import shlex
    args = self.tox_args
    if args:
        args = shlex.split(self.tox_args)
    else:
        args = ""
    errno = tox.cmdline(args=args)
    sys.exit(errno)


entry_points ={}
distutils_ext = {'distutils.setup_keywords': [
                    "tox_requires = setuptools.dist:check_requirements", ]
                 }
entry_points.update(distutils_ext)

setup(
      install_requires=['six', 'numpy', 'matplotlib', 'scipy', 'astropy>=1',
                  'Pillow', ],

    cmdclass={
        'test': PyTest,  # this is to run python setup.py test
        'tox': Tox,
    },

    # list of packages and data
    packages=find_packages(),

    # tests
    tests_require=['pytest', 'pytest-cov'],
    tox_requires=['tox'],
    # other keywords, mostly metadata
)
```

If I run `python setup.py sdist`, I get a warning at the beginning:

```
/usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py:267: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'tox_requires'
  warnings.warn(msg)
```

but then the sdist works fine and it creates a tar.gz file that I can use to install my package.

But if I run it a second time, it starts with (it's the beginning of Pillow building):

```
warning: no previously-included files found matching '.editorconfig'
Building using 4 processes
_imaging.c: In function ‘getink’:
```

and begins building all the required packages into .eggs directory.

If I remove the *egg-info directory I can rerun the command.
If I comment out the `tox_requires=[...]` line, I can build the sdist as many times as I want.

Now according to the [setuptools documentation](https://pythonhosted.org/setuptools/setuptools.html#adding-setup-arguments) the command above should be the correct way to run add new arguments to the setup function.

---

As per the subtitle, the problem is not only with `sdist` but it's probably due to my non-understanding on how setuptools and requirements work.

If I run `python setup.py tox` in a place without tox already installed I get, after the installation of some testing package it should not install (namely `pytest` and `pytest-cov`):

Traceback (most recent call last):
   [...]
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/setuptools/command/test.py", line 127, in with_project_on_sys_path
        func()
      File "setup.py", line 65, in run_tests
        if self.distribution.tox_requires:
    AttributeError: Distribution instance has no attribute 'tox_requires'

---

[Update] The `tox_requires` also confuse very badly pip during installation. If it is commented out I can install the package without any issue; otherwise it begins to compile the source of the packages and it systematically fails because it doesn't find `numpy` while building stuff like `scipy`

---

How can I get setuptools to recognize and properly use `tox_requires`?

Once this issue is fixed, I think that I can get rid of the spurious installations here doing a better job at implementing the `Tox` class, maybe overriding more things from `test` or deriving it directly from `Command`

Comment: Consider renaming the title of your question to: Fix `setup.py` to work with `sdist` and `tox`

Comment: If I had only tox called by the ``setup.py test`` it would work. The problem is not tox per se, but having ``tox_requires`` in the ``setup`` function.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Complete (working) solution described below consist of 8 files (incl. short
`README.rst`) and has in total 43 lines of code. This is less then code in your
original question.

Despite of being so short, it supports many development and testing scenarios
in very convenient way.

Anyway, it does not answer exactly your question, but I am sure, it fulfils the
requirements which were behind it.

## Three lines long `setup.py`

Technically it may be possible to put `test` command including `tox` automation into your `setup.py`, however, the result may be very messy and difficult to understand.

The same result can be achieved in much simpler way:

- for developer assume:

  - using `git`
  - having `tox` installed into system
- for package user:

  - there are no special requirements to install the resulting package
- (optional) if you want your users to test the package by single command and keep test reports collected in central server:

  - install `devpi-server` and give your users access to it
  - ask your users to install `$ pip install devpi`

The solution builds on following tools and packages:

- [`pbr`](http://docs.openstack.org/developer/pbr/): simplify package creation incl. versioning via git tags and
  creation of `AUTHORS` and `ChangeLog` from git commit messages.
- [`pytest`](http://pytest.org/latest/): excelent testing framework, but any other framework can
  be used instead of it.
- [`tox`](https://testrun.org/tox/latest/): excellent build and test automation tool.
- [`coverage`](http://coverage.readthedocs.org/en/latest/): tools to measure test coverage (working simpler then
  `pytest-cov`)

Optionally you may also use:

- `devpi-server`: private PyPi server with password protected
  access. Allows simple testing and provides test reports collection.
- [`devpi`](http://doc.devpi.net/latest/): tool similar to pip. Apart from installation also supports
  running `tox` defined tests (install, run tests, publish reports in on step).

### Authoring the package

Create new project directory and initialize git:

```
$ mkdir francesco
$ cd francesco
$ git init
```

#### Create a package or module

Here we create single module `francesco`, but the same works for more
modules or packages.

#### `francesco.py`

```
def main():
    print("Hi, it is me, Francesco, keeping things simple.")
```

#### `requirements.txt`

Create list of packages for actual installation of the package:

```
six
```

#### `test_requirements.txt`

Define packages required for testing:

```
pytest
coverage
```

#### `tests/test_it.py`

Initiate the test suite:

```
from francesco import main


def test_this():
    main()
    print("All seems fine to me")
    assert True
```

#### `setup.py`

Did you dream of stupid simple `setup.py`? Here it goes:

```
from setuptools import setup

setup(setup_requires=["pbr"], pbr=True)
```

#### `setup.cfg`

Metadata belong to configuration file:

```
[metadata]
name = francesco
author = Francesco Montesano
author-email = fm@acme.com
summary = Nice and simply installed python module supporting testing in different pythons
description-file = README.rst
[files]
modules=francesco
[entry_points]
console_scripts =
    francesco = francesco:main
```

#### `tox.ini`

To configure tox automated builds and tests:

```
[tox]
envlist = py27, py34

[testenv]
commands =
    coverage run --source francesco -m pytest -sv tests
    coverage report
    coverage html
deps =
    -rtest_requirements.txt
```

#### `README.rst`

Never forget `README.rst`:

```
===========================================
Complex package with 3 line long `setup.py`
===========================================

Can we keep`setup.py` simple and still support automated testing?

...
```

### `tox`: build sdist and run tests in all supported python versions

Being in the project directory root, just run single command `tox`:

```
$ tox
GLOB sdist-make: /home/javl/sandbox/setuppy/setup.py
py27 inst-nodeps: /home/javl/sandbox/setuppy/.tox/dist/francesco-0.0.0.zip
py27 runtests: PYTHONHASHSEED='2409409075'
py27 runtests: commands[0] | coverage run --source francesco -m pytest -sv tests
============================= test session starts ==============================
platform linux2 -- Python 2.7.9, pytest-2.8.7, py-1.4.31, pluggy-0.3.1 -- /home/javl/sandbox/setuppy/.tox/py27/bin/python2.7
cachedir: .cache
rootdir: /home/javl/sandbox/setuppy, inifile: 
collecting ... collected 1 items

tests/test_it.py::test_this Hi, it is me, Francesco, keeping things simple.
All seems fine to me
PASSED

=========================== 1 passed in 0.01 seconds ===========================
py27 runtests: commands[1] | coverage report
Name           Stmts   Miss  Cover
----------------------------------
francesco.py       2      0   100%
py27 runtests: commands[2] | coverage html
py34 inst-nodeps: /home/javl/sandbox/setuppy/.tox/dist/francesco-0.0.0.zip
py34 runtests: PYTHONHASHSEED='2409409075'
py34 runtests: commands[0] | coverage run --source francesco -m pytest -sv tests
============================= test session starts ==============================
platform linux -- Python 3.4.2, pytest-2.8.7, py-1.4.31, pluggy-0.3.1 -- /home/javl/sandbox/setuppy/.tox/py34/bin/python3.4
cachedir: .cache
rootdir: /home/javl/sandbox/setuppy, inifile: 
collecting ... collected 1 items

tests/test_it.py::test_this Hi, it is me, Francesco, keeping things simple.
All seems fine to me
PASSED

=========================== 1 passed in 0.01 seconds ===========================
py34 runtests: commands[1] | coverage report
Name           Stmts   Miss  Cover
----------------------------------
francesco.py       2      0   100%
py34 runtests: commands[2] | coverage html
___________________________________ summary ____________________________________
  py27: commands succeeded
  py34: commands succeeded
  congratulations :)
```

### Getting the sdist

```
ls .tox/dist
francesco-0.0.0.zip
```

### Developing in Python 2.7 virtualenv

#### Activate Python 2.7 virtualenv

```
$ source .tox/py27/bin/activate
```

#### Run tests

```
(py27) $ py.test -sv tests

==============================================================================================
test session starts
===============================================================================================
platform linux2 -- Python 2.7.9, pytest-2.8.7, py-1.4.31, pluggy-0.3.1
-- /home/javl/sandbox/setuppy/.tox/py27/bin/python2.7 cachedir: .cache
rootdir: /home/javl/sandbox/setuppy, inifile: collected 1 items

tests/test_it.py::test_this Hi, it is me, Francesco, keeping things
simple. All seems fine to me PASSED

============================================================================================
1 passed in 0.01 seconds
============================================================================================
```

#### Measure test coverage

```
(py27)$ coverage run --source francesco -m pytest -sv tests
.....
(py27)$ coverage report
Name           Stmts   Miss  Cover
----------------------------------
francesco.py       2      0   100%
```

#### View coverage report in web browser

```
(py27)$ coverage html
(py27)$ firefox htmlcov/index.html
```

### Release new package version

#### (optional) Install local `devpi-server`

The installation of devpi-server is not covered here, but is very
simple, especially, if you install only to your local machine for your
personal testing.

#### Commit source code, assign version tag

Make sure, all your source code is commited.

Assing version tag:

```
$ git tag -a 0.1
```

#### Rerun the tests by tox and build sdist

Make sure, you have deactivated virtualenv (otherwise it conflicts with
tox):

```
(py27)$ deactivate
```

Run the `tox`:

```
$ tox
.....
...it builds as usual, may fail, if you have forgotten to commit some changes or files...
```

Find the sdist for new version of your package:

```
$ ls .tox/dist/francesco-0.1.0.
.tox/dist/francesco-0.1.0.zip
```

**You are done.** You may distribute your new tested versions of your package
to users as usually.

#### (optional) Upload the sdist to devpi-server and test it locally

Following steps assume, you have `devpi-server` installed and running.

```
$ devpi login javl
...enter your password...
$ devpi upload .tox/dist/francesco-0.1.0.zip
```

#### Test the package in clean environment

(deactivate virtualenv if active) :

```
$ cd /tmp
$ mkdir testing
$ cd testing
$ devpi test francesco
received http://localhost:3141/javl/dev/+f/4f7/c13fee84bb7c8/francesco-0.1.0.zip
unpacking /tmp/devpi-test6/downloads/francesco-0.1.0.zip to /tmp/devpi-test6/zip
/tmp/devpi-test6/zip/francesco-0.1.0$ tox --installpkg /tmp/devpi-test6/downloads/francesco-0.1.0.zip -i ALL=http://localhost:3141/javl/dev/+simple/ --recreate --result-json /tmp/devpi-test6/zip/toxreport.json
-c /tmp/devpi-test6/zip/francesco-0.1.0/tox.ini
py27 create: /tmp/devpi-test6/zip/francesco-0.1.0/.tox/py27
py27 installdeps: -rtest_requirements.txt
py27 inst: /tmp/devpi-test6/downloads/francesco-0.1.0.zip
py27 installed: coverage==4.0.3,francesco==0.1.0,py==1.4.31,pytest==2.8.7,six==1.10.0,wheel==0.24.0
py27 runtests: PYTHONHASHSEED='3916044270'
py27 runtests: commands[0] | coverage run --source francesco -m pytest -sv tests
============================= test session starts ==============================
platform linux2 -- Python 2.7.9, pytest-2.8.7, py-1.4.31, pluggy-0.3.1 -- /tmp/devpi-test6/zip/francesco-0.1.0/.tox/py27/bin/python2.7
cachedir: .cache
rootdir: /tmp/devpi-test6/zip/francesco-0.1.0, inifile:
collecting ... collected 1 items

tests/test_it.py::test_this Hi, it is me, Francesco, keeping things simple.
All seems fine to me
PASSED

=========================== 1 passed in 0.01 seconds ===========================
py27 runtests: commands[1] | coverage report
Name           Stmts   Miss  Cover
----------------------------------
francesco.py       2      0   100%
py27 runtests: commands[2] | coverage html
py34 create: /tmp/devpi-test6/zip/francesco-0.1.0/.tox/py34
py34 installdeps: -rtest_requirements.txt
py34 inst: /tmp/devpi-test6/downloads/francesco-0.1.0.zip
py34 installed: coverage==4.0.3,francesco==0.1.0,py==1.4.31,pytest==2.8.7,six==1.10.0,wheel==0.24.0
py34 runtests: PYTHONHASHSEED='3916044270'
py34 runtests: commands[0] | coverage run --source francesco -m pytest -sv tests
============================= test session starts ==============================
platform linux -- Python 3.4.2, pytest-2.8.7, py-1.4.31, pluggy-0.3.1 -- /tmp/devpi-test6/zip/francesco-0.1.0/.tox/py34/bin/python3.4
cachedir: .cache
rootdir: /tmp/devpi-test6/zip/francesco-0.1.0, inifile:
collecting ... collected 1 items

tests/test_it.py::test_this Hi, it is me, Francesco, keeping things simple.
All seems fine to me
PASSED

=========================== 1 passed in 0.01 seconds ===========================
py34 runtests: commands[1] | coverage report
Name           Stmts   Miss  Cover
----------------------------------
francesco.py       2      0   100%
py34 runtests: commands[2] | coverage html
____________________________________________________________________________________________________ summary _____________________________________________________________________________________________________
  py27: commands succeeded
  py34: commands succeeded
  congratulations :)
wrote json report at: /tmp/devpi-test6/zip/toxreport.json
posting tox result data to http://localhost:3141/javl/dev/+f/4f7/c13fee84bb7c8/francesco-0.1.0.zip
successfully posted tox result data
```

You may check the test results in web browser:

```
$ firefox http://localhost:3141
```

then search for "francesco" package, click the package name, find in table
column named "tox results", click there to show environment set up and test
results.

### Let your users test the package

Let's assume, your `devpi-server` is running and your user has access to it.

The user shall have `devpi` command installed:

```
$ pip install devpi
```

(note, this tool is not installing anything from the `devpi-server`)

Help your user to gain access to `devpi-server` (not covering here).

Then the user just runs the test:

```
$ devpi test francesco
```

After the test is run (it is automatically using `tox`, but user does not have
to care about that), you will find test results on the same place on devpi web
interface as you found yours before.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I got more or less to the same conclusion: drop tox stuff in the setup.py. Now I have a test suite written using py.test and I use tox to run tests, create the documentation and the coverage reports across all the python versions I test. And I'm investigating ways to setup a simple pypi like server to share code with colleagues. I'll look into devpi: this a very valuable pointer. `devpi test` requires that the test suite is shipped with the package. Does `pbr` takes care of it or do I have to force it somehow (e.g. with MANIFEST)? ps: we are using svn :(

Comment: As you pointed out, your answer doesn't cover the why setuptools behaves so badly. It looks like some weird side effect. Do you think that I should report it to setuptools as a bug of some kind?

Comment: @FrancescoMontesano `devpi-server` is really good private PyPi server - easy to install, supports authenticated access, multiple stages for testing and releasing packages. Regarding `pbr`: there is no need to use `MANIFEST`, it takes care of it. My example above is complete. I did also a test, if a user without `tox` installed (only having `devpi` client) can run the `devpi test` and yes - it works like a charm.

Comment: @FrancescoMontesano Regarding using `svn`. I am not sure, if `pbr` works well with it (it tries to keep options to the minimum but there are some SVN related tests in the repository - so it might work). If you do not succeed with `pbr`, try alternative `packit`, which extend it (but I do not use SVN so I do not know its support either).

Comment: @JanVlicinsky: thank you very much for all the great suggestions. If only I knew about packit/pbr one year ago... ps: I'll wait one day or two before assigning the bounty

Comment: @FrancescoMontesano Regarding bug report to `setuptools` it is up to you. Personally I would not invest time into that (you would have to create good minimal failing example, react to feedback and I doubt you will ever really use it.)